# Django REST Framework PUT doesn't create new object?

Tags: django, http, django-rest-framework

When sending `PUT` request to `generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` with a URL like `site.com/demos/:id` where `id` doesn't match any existing object in the database, a 404 response will be returned. But according to [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4):

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload.

Doesn't this violate the RFC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It clearly violates the intended semantics of PUT. Returning 404 on PUT doesn't make any sense, as PUT doesn't require the resource to be present upfront.

Comment: So, what `PUT` should return in this case instead?

Comment: It should either succeed (preferably), or return a status code that indicates that PUT for resource creation is not supported (for instance, 409).

Comment: I have never seen such behavior by default in a bunch of mainstream frameworks, most of them return `404` if a matched record does not exist. By the way, because the question related to drf, returning 409 is not a good idea, e.g. by default endpoint will return it if somewhere already defined the same endpoint. It might be hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, no. I would like to have here the full quote:

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be
>   created or replaced with the state defined by the representation
>   enclosed in the request message payload.  A **successful** PUT of a given
>   representation would **suggest** that a subsequent GET on that same target
>   resource will result in an equivalent representation being sent in a
>   200 (OK) response.  **However, there is no guarantee that**

How can you see there is only "suggestion" and no any guarantees, generally it's a piece of good advice to follow RFC rules (and Django mostly does), remember that REST is just architectural style and it is still up to you how to implement it.

Comment: I don't think this quotation really answers the question, it just implies what could possibly happen **after** the PUT request.